# Connect jquery functions with html links

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to learn html and jquery.  My issue is that I have box that I want to modify based on what the user clicks.  For example if the user clicks fade the box should fade and slide would make the box slide.  I'm stuck on how to connect one box with multiple functions and links.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $ (function() {
        $('a').click(function() {
            $('#box').fadeOut(3000);
        });
    });

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="box"></div>
<li><a href="#">fade</a></li>
<li><a href="#">slide down</a></li>
<li><a href="#">slide right</a></li>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#box
{
background: red;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Use an ID or class selector to select different links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give your anchors ids and setup events for each id.

```
<li><a href="#" id="fade">fade</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="slided">slide down</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="slider">slide right</a></li>
```

And for each event, do the respective animations

```
$('#fade').on('click', function() {
          $('#box').fadeOut(3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your functions into a document.ready statement and add a selector on your LI's

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('a.fade').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#box').fadeOut(3000);
});

//rest of animate functions

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GT9jh/

Answer (score 0):

You could so something like this: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xc7EP/)**.

**HTML**

```
<div id="box"></div>
<li><a rel="fade" href="#">fade</a></li>
<li><a rel="slide down" href="#">slide down</a></li>
<li><a rel="slide right" href="#">slide right</a></li>​
```

**jQuery**

```
$('a').click(function() {
    effect = $(this).attr('rel').split(' ')[0];
    direction = $(this).attr('rel').split(' ')[1];
    $('#box').hide(effect, { direction: direction }, 1000);
});​
```